# CSV: awk change column value

Tags: shell, csv, awk

I try to parse a csv file and need to change some values for further processing.

The csv file contains a date col (column number 4), which contains values like this:
2016032100 
2016032318
etc.

I want to change all date values in the csv file from
2016032102 to this:
2016-03-21 02:00:00

I tried the following:

```
echo "$(awk -F';' -v OFS=';' '$4=${4:0:4}-${4:4:2}-${4:6:2} ${4:8:2}:00:00"' $FILE)" > $FILE
```

But this of course does not work.

I also tried to put the conversion into a function, but this also does not work.

Do you have any idea?

Comment: This is important - **awk is not shell** so do not expect shell syntax to work in an awk script any more than you'd expect shell syntax to work in a C or Java (or any other language) program. [edit] your question to show concise, testable sample input and expected output so we can help you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Never do:

```
echo "$(command $FILE)" > $FILE
```

for any value of "command" as the shell could cheerfully empty $FILE before it calls "command" to read it. Do this instead:

```
command "$file" > tmp && mv tmp "$file"
```

I also quoted the variable and changed it from upper to lower case as both things are also important (google it or read any shell book).

Now back to your specific question, this is what your code seems to be trying to do:

```
awk 'BEGIN{FS=OFS=";"} {$4=substr($4,1,4)"-"substr($4,5,2)"-"substr($4,7,2)" "substr($4,9,2)":00:00"} 1' "$file"
```

Whether or not that does what you want will depend on the rest of the contents of your CSV which we haven't seen yet but which isn't actually a Comma-Separated-Value (CSV) file.

Answer (score -1):

you can use the python csv module to read the file, datatime module to convert

```
import datetime
pythonTime = datetime.datetime.strptime("2016032100", "%Y%m%d%H")
print pythonTime.strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")
```

Comment: Sorry, but I only can use shell. But Ed Mortons solution works perfect.